# Setting CDR fields in "connected" macro

Tags: macros, asterisk

I am using Asterisk's queue app. When caller's call is picked up by queue member I want to set some CDR variables.

But problem is, that the "connected" macro is executed in queue member's channel (It should be caller's channel in my opinion)

```
exten => XXX, n,Queue(sales,tc,,,,,QueueConnected)

[macro-QueueConnected]
exten => s,1,NoOp()
exten => s,n,Set(CDR(somevar)=someval)
```

I can use "c" option for queue and the dialplan will continue after caller or member hangup, but it is too late to setup CDR values, because it is already emitted.

Can anybody help me with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out by using [HangupHandlers](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Hangup+Handlers)

```
exten => XXX, n,Set(CHANNEL(hangup_handler_push)=_hnd,s,1);
exten => XXX, n,Queue(sales,tc,,,,,QueueConnected)

[_hnd]
exten => s,1,NoOp()
exten => s,n,Set(CDR(somevar)=someval)
```

Works like a charm